# Cucumber After hook is being executed before scenario ends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, hook

I have an After hook in hooks.rb that deletes users created in the last scenario.
I started to notice that when tests run *at a specific time of the day*, this hook is being executed *in the middle of a scenario*. 
There is a method that executes until a certain line and then the hook executes just before an assert command in that method, which fails because of it.
The tests are run from a batch file ("ruby file_name.rb").

Does anyone have an idea why this might happen or how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you run your tests from command line like following?

```
$ cucumber
```

I would suggest to use debugger gem. You could add debugger statement just before you think is failing and then use some debugger commands

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps related to:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/52

Issue 52 is mostly fixed on the master, but I think there are a few remaining tests broken that need to be fixed before release.

Regardless of that, you might instead try using the `database_cleaner` gem for this purpose in general.  We use a clean database before every scenario for testing to ensure we have discrete tests that cannot have false positive/negative results due to results of other tests.  We use the following:

```
begin
  # start off entire run with with a full truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  # continue with the :transaction strategy to be faster while running tests.
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end
```

And we load our test seeds before each run:
    Before do |scenario|
      load Rails.root.join('db/seeds.rb')
    end

Note that our seeds.rb checks which environment it is running in to keep it short.  A big seeds file run in this manner would significantly increase test run times, so be careful.